# How do you calculate extra costs incurred if a project overruns its schedule?

Tags: ms-project, schedule-risk, pmbok

If a project doesn't meet its planned schedule, how do you calculate any losses per day incurred? Is there a graphing function in MS Project that I can use to depict losses per day?

Comment: Cost Overrun also effected by the points given below: Geographical conditions .
Labor strike Deliverable of materials at time
Inexperienced employee's , poor planning , design changes. Small stakeholders/ developers who have their concept not clear .
poor cash flow .

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question; OP didn't ask for causes of cost overrun, he asked how to calculate the cost of a schedule slippage.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

There isn't really any such thing as a "daily loss" in project management, since most projects are cost centers rather than profit centers. For example, you'd be hard-pressed to treat most projects as the sole topic of a profit-and-loss statement.

However, you can certainly calculate the expenses of cost overruns due to a project exceeding its planned budget or schedule, and you may also be able to capture additional liabilities attributable to exceeding your planning values.

### Costs of Exceeding Your Planning Values

#### Cost Overruns

[Cost overruns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_overrun) are generally caused by exceeding your planned budget, which is often tied to your schedule. Overruns can often be calculated based on a daily "[burn rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_rate)" for the project. For example, if your project costs $10,000/day in labor and resources to operate, then a project that is two weeks overdue will probably have exceeded the planned budget by around $100,000.

#### Other Costs

On the other hand, there are other costs that aren't really cost overruns, but may still be liabilities to the project or the business when a deliverable is late. Some examples include:

- Contractual penalties for late delivery.
- [Opportunity costs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost).
- Lost market share.
- Intangibles such as tarnished branding or loss of goodwill.

Many of these numbers will be represented by project-specific planning values, and can't be generically calculated across projects, organizations, or industries. Your sales or marketing departments may be able to assist you in developing plug-in values for these additional liabilities if they aren't already part of your project's plan or cost structure.

Comment: Unplanned travel, additional resources required to meet the deadline are also cost overruns.